# Trim email address

Tags: magento-1.9, email, registration

I have been doing some user testing and noticed that lots of  people put in a space after/before their email address, especially if they are ordering from a mobile phone, **i.e. " name@domain.com ".**

Because of the space, magento shows a red box error on it and some users get confused and don't know what to do. Is there a easy way of trimming the space from the email, through either code or javascript?

Any guide for this will be appreciated.

Comment: Try this var email = " name@domail.com";
console.log(email.trim());

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to your site: (change #email_address with the ID of your email field)

```
<script>
jQuery("#email_address").blur(function(){
    var pretrim = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery(this).val(pretrim.trim());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below code in your file where you want to trim the text:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("email_address").onblur = function() {
        var val = document.getElementById("email_address").value;
        var str = val.trim();
        document.getElementById("email_address").value = str;
    }
</script>
```

This method will work even when you are not using jQuery.